# Which way is the best to call api from server side

Tags: django, server

I’m building web application with React.

And I’ve never experienced making backend server.

But I need to make a server to call api with private key.

Call api is the only thing that I’m going to do with server.

In this case, which way is the best?

Comment: This is actually a HUGE question, because you're going to have to learn how to use django first. I suggest you go to udemy.com and buy some courses on Django 2, and learn to use it, because it would take a long time to answer what you're asking here. Even if I / someone else explained, if you didn't know how to use django, you wouldn't even understand our answers.

Comment: First, Thank you for comment. You are right. I need to understand how server works first. But I just wanna know the way most of people use in this case(use only for api). Not only django, I think there is a lot of ways to implement with this problem.

Comment: Well in that case, to describe it without showing it, you would make `urlpatterns` with the arguments you'd need to trigger specific `views` *(a.k.a. functions)*, and the api would be used in that view. And if you needed to save their data, you would need some `Models` too. And this would all be after your `settings.py` file has been set up properly.